# Swagger turns query param into post body

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a POST operation in a SpringBoot `@RestController` that takes a query param and a request body:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/benchmark", method = POST)
public String startBenchmark(@QueryParam("numMessages") int numMessages, @RequestBody String body) {
```

Swagger UI will render 'numMessages' as parameter type "body". Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Spring's `@RequestParam` instead of Jersey `@QueryParam`

Comment: Just did exactly that, you were quicker than me though. :)